# Return a smart pointer dereference as a reference type

Tags: c++

```
const string& show_string(){
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> p = std::make_shared<std::string>("test");
    return *p;
}
```

A novice question：Will this usage cause dangling reference？

Comment: Yes, the shared pointer goes of out of scope at the end of the function and that means the refcount goes to 0 and the string gets destroyed.

Comment: Yes, You can only do this safely if show_string is a member function of a class and the shared_ptr is a member of that class, or if p is a static shared_ptr. In other words you need something to extend the lifetime of p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes

`std::shared_ptr` will `delete` the object it owns when the last `std::shared_ptr` sharing ownership of that object is destroyed.  In this case, `p` is the only `std::shared_ptr` pointing to your string, and it is local to `show_string`, so that string will be destroyed as soon as `show_string` returns, leaving the returned reference dangling.